# MongoDB find function running twice in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm following [this link](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/query/#query-by-a-top-level-field) for finding data in mongoDB using node.js
My code is:

```
var counter = 0;
var findMongo = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor =db.collection('new').find( { "_id": ObjectId("56da6fd166efee0350399c21") } );
    //var cursor =db.collection('new').find();
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        console.log(counter);
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            //console.dir(doc);
            //console.log(doc);

        } else {
            console.log("in else,not found");
            callback();
        }
    });
};


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    findMongo(db, function() {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Since I'm searching the DB with _id, findMongo should only run once.

I'm getting following result:

> counter 1
>
> counter 2
>
> in else,not found

Why is the findMongo function called twice?

Comment: Hi Shipra,
db.collection('new').find( { "_id": ObjectId("56da6fd166efee0350399c21") } ) will return your cursor. Cursor is like a pointer will give you current row location and its content. Once information has been read from current cursor, it will point to other row location and continue. At last, it will move to last location which does not exit and it will return not found.

In your case, you have 2 records and that's why cursor is showing counter 1 and 2 and then not found.
Hope this information helps you

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani `_id` is a primary key, so it's not possible to return more than one record. To the OP, uncomment your `console.log(doc)` and you will then clearly see the real reason this is happening.

Comment: `.find` vs `.findOne`, If you are desiring only one record to be returned then you must code properly too.

Comment: I am curious to know why there are two record for one same `ObjectId("56da6fd166efee0350399c21")`?

Comment: Yes, In your case, first counter value increase by one at line number 4, then at line number 7, it is increasing again. So counter count is 2 and you are using find instead of findOne, that's why it is iterating 2 times, one for record to get and other for check whether record is exists or not.

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani, there is no code about `console.log(counter);` in this question

Comment: @zangw technically its not possible existance of two records with same-id, its apparently coding mistake.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon, yes, you are right. It is not possible for two records with same id.

Comment: The other thing to note is that returning `null` after there are no more documents is the default behavior for `.each()`. I really hoped that you would have self realized you incremented the counter "outside" of the loop as well. But `.each()` is also deprecated if you looked at the documentation, and you should use [`.forEach()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach) instead

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani Should I use `cursor.close()` inside the `if`block?
Would it be right approach?

Comment: why don`t you use findOne method instead of find() method..?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to be noticed:

1 - You are using `counter = counter + 1;` twice, its just creating confusion.

2 - You should use `findOne` instead `find`, it makes sense and is good approach because you are interested in finding one-record only whereas there is no harm in using later one.

Here is how to use  [db.collection.findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db-collection-findone)

Comment: I think the 2 points I have notified for you are the answer to your question, thanks for marking answer correct, let me know if there is still confusion.

Comment: A counter increment outside of the loop is really a silly mistake that should have been pointed out rather than making an "answer" out of it. Even if there is only one result, there is no reason why a cursor should not be used. But the OP should have read the documentation that explained why the logging pattern produced something on a `null` result. So close for silly mistake that really isn't going to help anyone in real production code.

Comment: @BlakesSeven answer is target to know what was done wrong and what is right approach. Question was "why?" and answer is for that.

Comment: `counter = counter + 1;` was mentioned by mistake here, I'n my original code, it's not present. Apologies for the confusion. Editing the question.

Comment: Inside cursor.each().

Comment: @Shipra avoid making things unnecessarily complex, and follow what is right.